# XChange java Poloniex: Hot to set price for Limit Order

Tags: java, poloniex

I cannot figure out how to set the selling/buying price for my limit order for Poloniex Exchange using XChange java library.

Bellow is initialization and my method for placing Bids but there is not price for setting.

```
ExchangeSpecification exSpec = new ExchangeSpecification(PoloniexExchange.class);
exSpec.setApiKey(POLONIEX_API_KEY_PROP_NAME);
exSpec.setSecretKey(POLONIEX_API_SECRET_PROP_NAME);
Exchange poloniex = ExchangeFactory.INSTANCE.createExchange(exSpec);

//-- TRADE SERVICE.
TradeService tradeService = poloniex.getTradeService();

MarketDataService marketDataService = poloniex.getMarketDataService();
Ticker ticker = marketDataService.getTicker(CURRENCY_PAIR);
```

~

```
private static String placeBuyLimitOrder(TradeService tradeService) throws Exception {

    LimitOrder order = new LimitOrder(OrderType.BID, MAIN_IN_TRADE.divide(oldBid, 8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(8), CURRENCY_PAIR, null, null, oldBid.subtract(Utils.SATOSHI));
    order.setOrderFlags(null);

    String orderId = tradeService.placeLimitOrder(order);

    return orderId;
}
```

This way sets my bid price equal to the highest bid in auction, but i would like to set i even higher. Does anyone know hot to set bid/ask price by myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
LimitOrder order = new LimitOrder(OrderType.BID, MAIN_IN_TRADE.divide(oldBid, 8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(8), CURRENCY_PAIR, null, null, oldBid.subtract(Utils.SATOSHI));
```

to :

```
LimitOrder order = new LimitOrder(OrderType.BID, MAIN_IN_TRADE.divide(oldBid + 0.005, 8, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(8), CURRENCY_PAIR, null, null, oldBid.subtract(Utils.SATOSHI));
```

if you want `0.005` higher